# Moss 2007: Change Label of Search Option (Advanced Search)

Tags: sharepoint, search, moss

I've created a custom search page with some defined options in my search scope.

I have a metadata mapped `jobtitle`, and added the search option to my custom search.

```
<Property name="JobTitle" 
          ManagedName="title" 
          ProfileURI="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:Title"/>
```

I want to change my managed name to `jobtitle`, because title doesn't hit the dutch word for jobtitle. I changed the managed name to `jobtitle`, after applying the changes it wouldn't change the label.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think where you say "to jobtitle" you mean "from jobtitle".
Where you say, "it wouldn't change the title" I think you mean "the label was unchanged".
I don't have enough rep to edit your question.

Comment: I agree.  This question is worded poorly.  I would love to help but can't really figure out what you did...or what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little difficult to know exactly what you're problem is since you are using a custom search page.

I am assuming you created a new Managed property and mapped it to something.  Then you added it to the advanced search webpart via editing the `xsl/xml` (directions [here](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2006/07/found-it-how-to-add-properties-to.html)).  If you change the name of the property you just added you need to update the webpart as well.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the managed properties will not appear in the search results until the data is re-crawled. I suggest you reset the search index and do a full crawl.